# This breakpoint will not be hit

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I looked at numerous posts concerning this problem but none of them apply in my case.
I have a C++ class in one file that has 3 methods. I can set a breakpoint in one method. However, I cannot set a breakpoint on any line of code in the other two methods. This class is build as a library with DEBUG set. All optimizations are turned off. 
  Below is the code for the two problem methods in this class.

> Blockquote

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <afxwin.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <io.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Log.h"


CLog::CLog()
{
    ptLog = NULL;  // this is the file ptr
}
void CLog::Init()
{
    int iFD;
    DWORD iLength;
    int iStat;
    HMODULE hMod;
    std::string sPath;
    std::string sFile;
    int i;

    hMod = GetModuleHandle(NULL);  // handle to this execuatble

    std::cout << "Module = " << hMod;
    if(hMod)
    {
// Use two bytes ASCII (UNICODE) if set by compiler

        char acFile[120];
        // Full path name of exe file
        GetModuleFileName(hMod, acFile, sizeof(acFile));
        std::cout << "File Name = " << acFile<<"\n";
        // extract file name from full path and append .log
        sPath = acFile;
        i = sPath.find_last_of("\\/");
        sFile = sPath.substr(i + 1);
        sFile.copy(acFile, 120);
        std::cout << " File Name Trunc = " << sFile;
        sFile.append(".log");
        iStat = fopen_s(&ptLog, sFile.data(), "a+");  // append log data to file
        std::cout << "fopen stat = " << iStat;
        if (iStat != 0)    // failed to open error log
        {
                return;
        }
        iFD = _fileno(ptLog);
        iLength = _filelength(iFD);
// Check length. If too large rename and create new file.
        if (iLength > MAX_LOG_SIZE)
        {
            fclose(ptLog);
            char acBakFile[80];
            strcpy_s(acBakFile, 80, acFile);
            strcat_s(acBakFile, ".bak");   // new name of old log file
            remove(acBakFile);  // remove previous bak file if it exists
            rename(acFile, acBakFile);
            fopen_s(&ptLog, acFile, "a+");   // Create new log file

        }
    }// end if (hMod)

}
```

> ,,,

ptLog is declared as FILE *
 This class is invoked with the following code:

> 

```
#include <iostream>
#include "..\Log\Log.h"

int main()
{
    CLog Logger;

    Logger.Init();
    Logger.vLog((char *) "Hello \n");
}
```

> Blockquote
>     This code is also compiled as debug. If a set a breakpoint on "Loggger.Init()"
>   the debugger will hit the breakpoint. If select 'Step Into' it will not enter
>   the code in the Init() method. The code does execute since I can see the text on the console. If I put breakpoints anywhere in the Init() method they do not break.

Comment: Maybe you need to do a clean build. With that said I have seen cases where Visual Studio optimizes out a constructor or destructor in Debug build. When this happens and I want to debug I do something like adding the following `std::cerr << "Got Here" << __FUNCTION__;`

Comment: Will the `CLog` default constructor be called? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Compilers have been known to throw away code that isn't used, share common function returns, jump to other places in the code.  If you set a breakpoint on a statement, it may not be hit because of these reasons (there could be more).  Another issue would be that there is no debugging information for statement.  This is often true when trying to step through libraries.

Comment: I already tried a clean build and adding debug statements. The debug text does appear on the console but none of the breakpoints work. I can't even 'step into' the function.

Comment: The CLog class was compiled as debug with all optimizations turned off. I tried different breakpoints on different lines to no avail. I check and it did produce a .pdb file. One onm the methods in the class does allow breakpoints.

Comment: I suggest you could position the mouse to the breakpoint which doesn’t work. If `the current source code is different from the version built into` happens, you could select `Debug->Options->Debugging->General` and clear the `Require source files that exactly match the original version` option. You could also refer to [Microsoft Docs]( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/troubleshooting-breakpoints?view=vs-2019).

Answer (score 0):

I did the following:
Removed log.lib from the input to the Linker.
Obviously, the Link failed due to unresolved externals.
Put back log.lib and rebuilt.
Turned off the option "Require source files that exactly match the original version"
Debug and breakpoints worked.
Enabled the option.
Retried debug and the breakpoints still worked.
Did a full rebuild and breakpoints worked.

I don't really understand it because I had performed numerous cleans and rebuilds
previously.

Answer (score 0):

I did find another issue. I had '/clr' option on.
This is for Common Language Runtime support for the .lib.
The module linked to it did not have Common Language Runtime on. In this case,
the breakpoints were ignored. When I turned off '/ clr', the breakpoints
functioned properly